# How can I write a voice command that centers the active window using an external program?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. How can I write a voice command that center the active window using Advanced Scripting? The command should support a multi-monitor setup, and the centering should be done within the monitor where the window is located.

I am aware that this could the achieved easily [using AHK](https://superuser.com/q/403187/116475) but I'd prefer to avoid having voice commands that rely on an external program.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-write-a-voice-command-that-centers-the-active-window-using-an-external-program